# How do i get the caller classname from a static method of different class

Tags: java

Lets say, I have

```
public class ClassA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB.methodB();
    }
}
```

and I'm calling a static function of another class

```
public class ClassB{
    public static void methodB() {
        System.out.Println("<I want to print the classname of classA>");
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is that really necessary? This seems like a hacky XY problem. Why do you need this?

Comment: you could use the stackwalker comming with java 9 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/StackWalker.html and get one "step back" in your stack .. but thats quite dirty ;-)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use Log4j and I don't want to create the static Logger object in every class. So I have created a BaseLogger class that extends Logger (Log4j) with some custom static logging functions. When I call these functions that I have created (in BaseLogger class) from another class, they are logging the classname of BaseLogger but what I wanted to print is calling classname.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really (you could throw an exception and dig through the stack trace, but that is very slow and unnecessary).

Instead ask yourself the question why you think you need that?
Is it for logging purposes?

What does `methodB` need to know to perform its job.
If it needs to know something, it should just take a parameter and decide what to do based on that.